# How to Send N number of Requests at Same Time in IOS

Tags: ios

How to Send N number of Request to Server say I have 10 Xml Urls, I have to Hit the Server 10 urls at same time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

**Grand Central Dispatch**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.uploadXml", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT), ^(void)
{
      //Upload here . . 
});
```

You can set the number of concurrent requests as follows:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

**BBHTTP**

The [BBHTTP](https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/BBHTTP) and other network libraries support this. For example the executor below has 10 concurrent requests.

```
BBHTTPExecutor* xmlUploadExecutor = [BBHTTPExecutor initWithId:@"myApp.xmlUploder"];
xmlUploadExecutor.maxParallelRequests = 10;

BBHTTPRequest* request = [[BBHTTPRequest alloc]
                      initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://upload.url"]
                      andVerb:@"PUT"];


request.upLoadProgressBlock = ^(NSUInteger current, NSUInteger total) { /* ... */ };
request.finishBlock = ^(BBHTTPRequest* request) { /* ... */ };
[request setUploadData:yourData withContentType:@"text/xml"];

[xmlUploadExecutor executeRequest:request];
```

**Other Options**

You could also use another network library like AFNetworking or use an NSOperationQueue

Comment: How to send Xml url Requests iam not using any facebook or Twitter

Comment: BBHTTP is a generic network lib. Let me customize that example for you.

Comment: Keep in mind you may not get responses at the same time, so you'll need to handle each one, and if any are dependent on another one you should handle them accordingly.